# How do I alter an existing primary key in a table?

Tags: firebird

I have a table with a primary key already defined in it. I would like to add a column to it which must also be part of the primary key. How can that be done?

Comment: ALTER TABLE provider DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(person, place, thing);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `PK_MY_TABLE` is constraint name of existing primary key :

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE;

COMMIT;

alter table MY_TABLE
add constraint PK_MY_TABLE
primary key (ID,ID_1);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE, ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (ID,ID_1);
```

Comment: Is there no single command to achive it without having to drop the constraint first? I would most probably use the ALTER TABLE name ADD statement to add the column.

Comment: It still drops the constraint first. :)

Comment: the existing primary key must drop first because there must be only one PK

Comment: I suppose an ALTER TABLE name ALTER CONSTRAINT would be nice.

Comment: Works beatifully.. My Code: ALTER TABLE YOUR_ACCOUNT DROP CONSTRAINT INTEG_4, ADD CONSTRAINT INTEG_4 PRIMARY KEY (IDENTIFIER,YOUR_NAME);

Answer (score 3):

An elegant way to do this in single query

In MYSQL

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID,ID_1);
```

FOR FIREBIRD:-

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP CONSTRAINT TEST_CONST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID,ID_1)
```

Comment: As far as I know the DROP PRIMARY KEY does not work in firebird.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do this is one step, with firebird

you have to do, quoting above example

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE;

alter table add id_1;

COMMIT;

alter table MY_TABLE
add constraint PK_MY_TABLE
primary key (ID,ID_1);

commit;

It is strongly recommended that this is done when you have sole use of the database

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using an execute block:

```sql
EXECUTE BLOCK

AS

  DECLARE NOMBRE VARCHAR(100);

BEGIN

 FOR

  SELECT RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'

  INTO NOMBRE

  DO

  IF (NOMBRE IS NOT NULL) THEN

  BEGIN

    EXECUTE STATEMENT 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT ' || NOMBRE;

  END

  SUSPEND;

END
```